# Есть возможность собрать SFML проект под процессор ARM8 64-битной архитектуры?

Tags: android, c++, sfml, arm, x86-64

В официальном руководстве поддерживается только сборка под armeabi-v7a. Есть какие-нибудь возможности или способы собрать SFML проект под ARM8 64-битной архитектуры?
Если есть, хотелось бы их узнать.

Comment: пробовали указать правильный тулчейн и собрать?

Comment: Нет, ещё не пробовал. Пробовал только под armeabi - v7a.